# Docker build error: failed to add the host

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm facing an unexpected error when running `docker build`, and I say *unexpected* because I haven't changed my `Dockerfile` for a while, and it had worked fine for the last time two weeks ago, but now I'm getting the following error:

> failed to create endpoint optimistic_spence on network bridge: failed to add the host (veth9fc3a03) <=> sandbox (veth15abfd6) pair interfaces: operation not supported

In case it is of any help:

- Docker version is 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa8257ec
- I don't see any container with `docker ps`
- Systemd returns an active status for the docker process (`sudo systemctl status docker`)
- Build command is: `docker build -t user/repo:tag .`

`Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

LABEL version="current version"
LABEL description="A nice description."
LABEL maintainer="my@email.com"

RUN apk update && apk add \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make \
    git \
    && git clone https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git \
    && cd repo \
    && make \
    && cp program /bin \
    && rm -r /repo \
    && apk del g++ make git

WORKDIR /tmp

ENTRYPOINT ["program"]
```

Does anybody understand what is going on? Thank you!

**EDIT**
When combined with the `--network` option, the error changes a little, but it won't fix the problem. For example, `--network=host` gives the following:

> fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>
> ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/main: temporary error (try again later)
>
> WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.167438ca.tar.gz: No such file or directory
>
> fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
>
> ERROR: http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.4/community: temporary error (try again later)
>
> WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.a2e6dac0.tar.gz: No such file or directory
>   2 errors; 11 distinct packages available
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c apk update && apk add     gcc     g++     make     git     && git clone https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git     && cd repo     && make     && cp program /bin     && rm -r /repo     && apk del g++ make git' returned a non-zero code: 2

Comment: Try creating another network and adding it to that rather than the default one?

Comment: using the `--network` option does not fix the problem. I will update the question remarking this

Comment: Change your shell script so that each line is a RUN instruction in dockerfile. You may pinpoint which layer causes the error

Comment: Error occurs during the first RUN instruction: `RUN apk update`.

Comment: Does other instructions pass? Try something like echo or, better yet wget, so you can check if it can connect to internet. It might be a connection issue. Also, use alpine:latest maybe if possible?

Comment: It seems to be a connection error in fact. Running `wget` results in exactly the same error than above

Comment: Don't know if related, but i am using docker for win in Win10, and i cannot use hostname to connect to containers anymore. I used to be able to before.

Comment: I got the same error in docker build under Ubuntu. In my case the cause was that I was running a customer kernel, which Docker doesn't seem to like. Booting to stock kernel resolved the issue.

Answer (score 17):

Had the same error and `systemctl restart docker` nor pruning og images & system did not do it for me, I ended up rebooting my computer which seems o have resolved the issue.

Comment: This happens for me regularly  because of a Kernel update. So reboot is the way.

Comment: Yeah. Just restarted and it started working.

Comment: Tried `docker system prune --all`; **did not work.**
Tried `systemctl restart docker`; **did not work.**
Tried rebooting the computer; **worked.**

Answer (score 6):

It looks that something wrong happened with any `docker network bridge` and it doesn't let you to create the same because is "zombie".

Try with following steps:

1. `docker network prune`, and if it doesn't work, try with:
2. `docker system prune` <-- Careful, this also will purge your named volumes contents, i.e, volumes that are not assigned to a container. So, if you have volumes assigned to a container, you should have to re-build/create containers.
3. `/etc/init.d/docker restart`

Show me what happens and let's see, actually I need more info about your problem if it doesn't solve it to you.

Comment: I get the same error after running both `docker network prune` and `docker system prune` :(

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the possible causes. For me (and probably @testix) it was because i did a system upgrade (archlinux), so my kernel modules got upgraded, but i was still running the old kernel, so modules could not be loaded.
You can try do modprobe a random module:

```
modprobe vcan
modprobe: FATAL: Module vcan not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.7-arch1-1
```

This means that you have to reboot, (or use `--network` if you can get away with it).

Answer (score 1):

Two times I have faced this issue and the way to fix it has always been the same. I'm posting in case it can be of any help for somebody:

- First, make sure that the DNS server is properly set up (eg. setting DNS to 1.1.1.1).
- Second, restarting the docker daemon.

For those using systemd in Linux, systemctl restart did not the job for me. I had to stop and start docker to make it work. After that, I could login and pull images again.

Comment: For reference, restart Docker with systemctl with `systemctl restart docker`